# Fixing Linefeed breaks

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a pipe delimited text file that comes on a daily basis with line breaks as a result of an online feed interruption.

Every line in the file starts with `FORM_`, so i normally open the file in notepad++, use the find and replace for either `^[^FORM]` or `([^\S \r\n]*)\n([^\S\r\n]*)` and manually fix the mistake.

Due to limitation in technology where I work, I am writing a vb script, that will end up as an executable, to among other things fix this issue.

I have looked on here for some possible answers and below is what I tried:

Reading the file one line at a time, then using regex to replace either of the above search criteria:

```
objFixFormFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileLocation & filename, 1)
objWriteFormFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(FileLocation & NewFileName, True)
Do while not objFixFormFile.AtEndOfStream
    If strReader = "" THEN 
        strReader = objFixFormFile.ReadLine
    Else
        strReader = strReader & ";" & objFixFormFile.ReadLine
    End if 
Loop
ObjFixFormFile.Close                        
strCleansedLine = RegEx.Replace(strReader, ("[^\S \r\n]*)\n([^\S\r\n]*)", "")
strCleansedLine = RegEx.Replace(strReader, ";", "\n")
objWriteFormFile.Writeline(strWriter)
```

That didn't work. When I try to do the `.ReadAll` version of the above code out of 125,000 records I only end up with 59,000 records.

Can you please advise what is the best way of doing this, as it needs to run on a daily basis?

Comment: Can you add some failing samples and the part of the code where the RegEx is instantiated?

Comment: First: In the two `Replace` at the bottom you use `strReader` as input to both - shouldn't the second one have `strCleansedLine`? Secondly the same goes for the `WriteLine` statement - shouldn't that have the result of the second `Replace` (also `strCleansedLine`)?

Answer (score 0):

Only write the linebreak for the previous line if the current line starts with `FROM_`:

```
Do Until objFixFormFile.AtEndOfStream
    line = objFixFormFile.ReadLine
    If Left(line, 5) = "FROM_" And objFixFormFile.Line > 2 Then
        objWriteFormFile.WriteLine
    End If
    objWriteFormFile.Write line
Loop
objWriteFormFile.WriteLine

objFixFormFile.Close
objWriteFormFile.Close
```